# Remove Negative Sign From Textbox

Tags: c#

Software Utilize C#, VS-2005

How to Remove Nagative Sign From Textbox. my code is:

```
Private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        decimal t1 = 0;
        decimal t2 = 0;
        decimal res = 0;
        t1 = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
        t2 = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text);
        res = t1 - t2;
        textBox3.Text = res.ToString();
 }
```

if t1 have value 12000 and t2 have value 20000.  so result is 12000-20000 = -8000

I want to remove (-) sign from textbox. How can i do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The static [`Math.Abs` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.abs.aspx) is your friend.

```
res = Math.Abs(t1 - t2);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
textBox3.Text = Math.Abs(res).ToString();
```

Comment: Sure it works :-).  The ToString exists on all objects in .NET.

Answer (score 3):

ya put `(Math.Abs(res)).ToString();`

Answer (score 2):

Use [absolute value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.abs.aspx):

```
Math.Abs(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take the absolute value of the result of the subtraction.

```
res = Math.Abs(res)
```